# How to hide error "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach, notice

I have the following code, which works correctly. The Twitter Friends are listed correctly, however it seems that when the last item is displayed the error "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object" is displayed 4 times.

Since the code works as it should, I would like a way to hide these errors.

```
$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);
$tweets6 = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);
foreach ($tweets6 as $tweet)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < count($tweet); $i++)
    {
        echo $tweet[$i] -> name;
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: no, access the values properly and you won't have a problem, dont try to hide the errors and try to solve them, what does `$tweet6` contain anyway

Comment: $tweets6 is a list of objects, it is defined in my code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can add a checker if the object has a certain property before using its value

```
if (isset($tweet[$i]->name)) {
    // process

}
```

Answer (score 1):

replace this :

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($tweet); $i++)
```

with this :

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($tweet) - 1; $i++)
```

EDIT

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($tweet); $i++){
    if (isset($tweet[$i]->name)) {
        echo $tweet[$i] -> name;
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
```

try this

Comment: I had already tried that, it removed the error but also the last item

Comment: @user2675041 i had edited my code, so please go through that, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple if condition before print..

```
   $connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);
   $tweets6 = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);
foreach ($tweets6 as $tweet)
{
   for($i = 0; $i < count($tweet); $i++){  
     if($tweet[$i]){
        echo $tweet[$i] -> name;
        echo "<br />";
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer will work, PHP has the [`property_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) function to do this job and would be more appropriate. It will return true even if the property has a null value, which `isset()` does not.

```
if (property_exists($tweets[$i], "name")) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use if empty for prevent that notice.

```
$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);
$tweets6 = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);
foreach ($tweets6 as $tweet)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < count($tweet); $i++)
    {
        if(empty($tweet[$i]->name)) continue;
        echo $tweet[$i]->name;
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
```